# Unable to access Go server when hosted on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-ec2

I have created a project in Go using gin and it is working fine locally. However, when I tried deploying this on an EC2 instance on AWS, I was unable to access the APIs on the server.

I did a ssh into the hosted machine and gave a curl request (`curl localhost:8080`) and it gave a proper response. But any request from outside is not reachable.

The server is running on port 8080. I have opened the ports in the AWS security groups.

Is there any setting in Go/gin that I need to make for it to be accessible from the internet?

Sample code:

```
package main

import (
    "myConstants"
    "myDatabase"
    "myMiddleware"
    "onboarding"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {

    var db = myDatabase.DBConnect()

    router := gin.Default()

    router.Use(myMiddleware.RestrictInputContent)
    router.Use(myMiddleware.CheckToken(db))
    router.Use(myMiddleware.RequestLoggerMiddleware())

    router.POST("/signup", onboarding.Signup(db))
    router.POST("/login", onboarding.Login(db))
    router.POST("/logout", onboarding.Logout(db))
    router.GET("/", onboarding.Hello(db))

    defer db.Close()

    //Listen and serve
    router.Run("127.0.0.1:8080")

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't have to do anything special, try using `nmap` on your EC2 instance to make sure the port is really open.

Comment: I changed the router.Run from router.Run("127.0.0.1:8080") to router.Run(":8080") and it is working fine now

Comment: But aren't they both mean the same?

Comment: No. 127.0.0.1 (local host) is only the loop back interface on the machine. Binding to ":8080" means 0.0.0.0:8080 - which means all interfaces. Your external IP address isn't 127.0.0.1 but likely an IP on another interface (use ifconfig to discover them).

Comment: Sorry I read it quickly and didn't see the `127.0.0.1:8080`, that isn't binding it to `0.0.0.0:8080` so you're only listening on loopback

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Changed the router.Run from `router.Run("127.0.0.1:8080")` to `router.Run(":8080")` and it works.
As suggested by @elithrar and @user3591723
127.0.0.1 (local host) is only the loop back interface on the machine
Binding to ":8080" means 0.0.0.0:8080 - which means all interfaces